# Values from Controller to Service to Directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

my AngularJS web app needs (as you may guess) to show modal popups sometime. Before learning AngularJS I used to centralize my code using Namespaces, and I tipically put all the UI stuff in a proper namespace, like: *MyProj.UI.Dialogs.Modal.show()* (just an example).

Now I', trying to apply the same logic in AngularJS. So, I created a **directive**:

```
app.directive('modal', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/partials/site/modal.html'
    }
});
```

with the following template:

```
<div>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

so I can use the **modal** tag in my html.

Now, to control the modal behavior I'd like to use a **service**, something like:

```
angular.module('ui', [])
    .factory('ui', function ($rootScope) {
        var service = {
            showConfirm: function (title, text, callback) {
                $rootScope.showModal = true;
            }
        };

        return service;
    }
);
```

I'd use it from any **controller**:

```
app.controller('MyCntl', function (ui) {
    $scope.delete = function (referer) {
        ui.showConfirm("Confirm", "Please confirm action", function () {});
    }
});
```

But my question is: **how do I pass values from the controller, to the service, to the directive?**

Comment: take a look at this project https://github.com/doodeec/dcom-angular-dialog, you can either use it, or find there the way to do what you need

Comment: Thank you @doodeec I'll have a look at the code. I'm also using bootstrap, so I could use the library as is, but I'm curious to see how you made it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JLDDsTzSAHaitsZ4dxtL?p=preview

**Bind the service to the directive's scope:**

```
app.directive('modal', function (ui) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:{},
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        link: function(scope){
          scope.ui = ui;
        }
    }
});
```

**service:**

```
angular.module('ui', [])
    .factory('ui', function ($rootScope) {

        var _callback = null;

        var service = {
            confirm: function(confirmed){
              if(confirmed) _callback();
              service.show = false;
              _callback = null;
            },
            showConfirm: function (title, text, callback) {
                service.show = true;
                service.title = title;
                service.text = text;
                _callback = callback;
            }
        };

        return service;
    }
);
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-if="ui.show" class="modal">
    <h2>{{ui.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{ui.text}}</p>
    <button ng-click="ui.confirm(true)">ok</button>
    <button ng-click="ui.confirm(false)">cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @Ilan this is exactly what I needed, but I don't understand why on my site the "show" variable is ignored... weird! I tried to print the value inside the <modal> tag, and it show the exact value (true) but this won't show the modal anyway. Any idea? :(

Comment: I'm using angular 1.2.13

Comment: I tried also with ng-show but it doesn't change, it seems to ignore ui.show

Comment: However, if I use a global variable ($rootScope) is works, I'll use this way, until I discover what problem is about ui.show